# Tinymce and html content not keeps code the same

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I've trying to insert for ex. this code to get googlemaps in my webpage that i changes whole site in tinymce.

```
  <div id="g-map">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But what I get is this `<div id="g-map">&nbsp;</div>` any idé why that happens? I've got no clue so far tested changing htmlentitles to htmlspecial char when saving nothing seems to matter.

This is my tinymce.init options the get it to include javascript also

```
mode : "specific_textareas",
editor_selector : "editor",
relative_urls : false,
remove_script_host : false,
document_base_url : "http://localhost",
allow_script_urls: true,
remove_script_host : false,
convert_urls : true,
extended_valid_elements : "script[src|type|language]",
height: 500,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all that read this! As usually, after 1 hour of trying to sort it out, I took a break and found this gem as an answer `valid_elements : '*[*]'`. Hope that may help someone else at least.

Answer (score 0):

In [html Entities](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) NBSP represents a non-breaking space, also known as a empty space.

Also, I recommended you try this better editor: [CK Editor](http://ckeditor.com/). I think is the better than Tiny MCE.

Comment: If this help you don't forget validate.